# where do you programmatically set text for UILabels in a UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

where do you programmatically set text for UILabels in a UIView?

I tried in the init method and this doesn't work.  It doesn't set the text.

I've put the code in the parent controller that uses the UIView within it, but to me it would make more sense if I put it somewhere in the UIView code.

Background - doing programmatically has I'm doing localisation on the text

Comment: Is this UILabel an IB object? or is it created grammatically?

Comment: @ShantiKamichetty it is an IB object Shanti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initialization code should be in `initWithFrame:`, UIView's [designated initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html).

Alternatively you can implement `awakeFromNib` which is called on an object (such as a view) once it has been unarchived from a nib file.

Comment: Yes. IB objects will be initialized during the loading of the nib. Hence they won't be able to access them from the init function.

Answer (score 0):

In `-init` methods outlets from XIB do not exist yet.
I set the text for that kind of controls in `-viewDidLoad` routine

Comment: but in my case I'm in a UIView custom class (i.e. not a view controller), so I wouldn't have a "viewDidLoad".   I could set it from the parent controller, but I'm trying to find a way to include the code in the UIView custom class itself (hope that makes sense)